# LESS-generated stylesheet doesn't work

Tags: css, less, leaflet

I don't know what's going wrong, but I have the same style rules directly written as css (index.css) and written in less(style.less->style.css).
When I load my page with index.css, then my leaflet-map is shown correctly, but when I use style.css, everything is loaded, but the map-container has a height of 0px.

Because this all is a bit more complicated, I put you the code in a jsfiddle.

index.css: http://jsfiddle.net/Lhfy89kn/

style.css: http://jsfiddle.net/86y3y17v/

I'm searching for the solution since a year but I don't see the mistake because apart from the fact, that the rule is more precise when I precompile, so `body app map #map_canvas` instead of just `#map_canvas` I don't see any differences...

Hope you guys can help me!

P.S:I know the map-tag has a different purpose in HTML5 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your LESS generated stylesheet lacks the following CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Without this, none of the children containers have an appropriate height to display their contents. Here's an updated fiddle with the issue resolved:

http://jsfiddle.net/86y3y17v/1/

Comment: Thanks acicalli. I thought I tested that already but seems like I didn't -.-

Answer (score 0):

Use `html, body, map, #map_canvas` and not `html body map { height: 100%; }`

http://jsfiddle.net/86y3y17v/2/